# Facebook/Instagram webhook for DM not working anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, messenger, facebook-webhooks

We are using webhooks for "instagram" resource and then executing some logics based on type of webhook we receive. One of the webhook in the list is the "message" webhook which we were receiving till 16th may 2022 around 1:30 PM IST and then it suddenly stopped triggering from facebook.

Surprisingly we are still able to receive webhooks for other event types for same "instagram" resource from facebook (like 'message_reaction', 'comments' etc)

I don't know what is wrong here, as I haven't made any changes to the developer account which I am using for testing these webhooks. Can anyone help here, as we are stuck at a very important step in our product lifecycle?

Also I have started a thread on Facebook community also, Link to the same can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/727652275028497/?post_id=727652278361830)

[Screenshot to webhook setting page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzzzJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue couple of days ago, what I suggest you to do is first you can test your webhook using the the tests FB provides and make sure everything works fine on your side. If so, the threads and questions on FB community are rarely getting answered so I suggest you to report a bug on your app from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/) and the guys from FB are really helpful and will communicate with you within 2 working days max and follow up with you till you solve that issue.